# mqtt bad username or password

Tags: python, mqtt

I wrote the code about the gateway running on VS with python. The problem now is that I have configured the username and password of mqtt and the IP and port of the server, but the return value is rc=4 (bad username or password) , I use wireshark to capture packets, the CONNECT packet I sent is correct, but the return value shows bad username or password

```
def __doPost(self):
    self.__connectMqtt(host = host, port = port, mqttUsername = id, mqttPassword = token)

def __connectMqtt(self,host,port,mqttUsername,mqttPassword):
    # Username = mqttUsername.encode("utf-8")
    self.mqttc.username_pw_set(username=mqttUsername, password=mqttPassword)
    # self.mqttc.subscribe(self.setTopic,1)
    self.mqttc.on_connect=self.__on_connect
    self.mqttc.on_message=self.__on_message
    self.mqttc.on_publish=self.__on_publish
    self.mqttc.on_disconnect=self.__on_disconnect
    # self.mqttc.tls_set(ca_certs = r"C:\Users\chris\Desktop\MobiusPi-Project-Templates-1.0.5\helloworld-template\src\root.crt")
    self.mqttc.connect(host, port, keepalive=200)
    # self.publish(message = "SUPCON Test")
    self.mqttc.publish_to_mqtt = self.publish_to_mqtt()
    # self.mqttc.subscribe_gateway = self.subscribe_gateway()
    self.mqttc.loop_forever()

def __on_connect(self,client, userdata, flags, rc):
    """
        The value of rc indicates success or not:
        0: Connection successful
        1: Connection refused - incorrect protocol version
        2: Connection refused - invalid client identifier
        3: Connection refused - server unavailable
        4: Connection refused - bad username or password
        5: Connection refused - not authorised
        6-255: Currently unused.
    """
    if   rc==0:
        print("Connect successful")
    elif rc==1:
        print("incorrect protocol version")
    elif rc==2:
        print("invalid client identifier")
    elif rc==3:
        print("server unavailable")
    elif rc==4:
        print("bad username or password")
        # print (client,flags)
    elif rc==5:
        print("not authorised")
    elif 6<rc<255:
        print("Currently unused")
    else:
        print("Connect failed")

def __on_message(self,client, userdata, message):
    message=message.payload.decode('utf8')
    print('receive message:%s'%(message)) 

def __on_publish(self,client, userdata, mid):
    print('publish message success mid:%s'%(mid))
    
def __on_disconnect(self,client,userdata,rc):
    if rc==0:
        print('disconnect success')
    else:
        print('disconnect fail')
```

Comment: First off, don't post links to images here....too many chances its a virus so people won't click the link.
Second, What MQTT Broker are you running?  Post the output of the log file where the connection comes in and what it thinks is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

oh,i have been solved this problem.because every gateway have clientID, The server I need to connect to needs to specify the client ID, and it is not possible to connect to anything. I need to define the clientID to connect.

if your gateway don't connet the server,and return error is bad username or password, maybe is clientID is error.

Comment: you can use the wireshark to catch data pack